# Radwindow OnClientClose firing on open

Tags: javascript, telerik, radwindow

I have a radwindow which is opened using a javascript function as follows. However, when the radwindow pops up, the alert is displayed.

```
function OpenRadWindow() 
{
   var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();
   var oMailWnd;
   oMailWnd = window.radopen("MyModal.aspx");
   oMailWnd.set_title("Modal Window");
   oMailWnd.OnClientClose = HideActions();
   oMailWnd.set_modal(true);
}

function HideActions() {
   alert("Window Closed");
}
```

I have not been able to find anywhere that sets OnClientClose inside javascript. Could someone tell how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
oMailWnd.OnClientClose = HideActions();
```

is wrong. If you want to add a closing handler to the RadWindow object, you should use the [client-side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html)

e.g.

```
oMailWnd.add_close(HideActions);
```

Also, if you are going to show the window multiple times and you haven't set DestroyOnClose=true, I would suggest to clear the closing handler in the closing function in order to avoid stacking:

```
function HideActions(sender) {
    //remove the handler
    sender.remove_close(HideActions);
    //your code 
    alert("Window Closed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I had already set DestroyOnClose in the RadWindowManager for that reason.